# How to get running JBPM processes list using API's in normal java code

Tags: java, jbpm

Based on the user how to retrieve the list of running processes in normal java code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using persistence, then you can simply do: ksession.getProcessInstances() to get the list of all running processes. 
If you are using persistence, then, as far as I know, you will need to query the database since ksession.getProcessInstances() will always return an empty list.

Best Regards

Comment: When using persistence, you should use the history database to query for active instances, for example JPAProcessInstanceDbLog.findActiveProcessInstances(processId)